# foreign key field in admin model is not being validated at client side by parsley

Tags: django, django-admin, parsley.js

foreign key field in admin model is not being validated at client side by parsley.
These are my models

```
class Head(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=False, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Subject(models.Model):
    head = models.ForeignKey(Head, blank=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=False, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

while adding subject name field shows error if it is blank ,but it allows the head field with blank value